# I2C / TWI: set up atmega328p as slave

Tags: i2c, avr, wire-library, atmega

I try to run an atmega328p as a i2c slave. even with the bare minimum the slave acts as its not wired at all: NACK is transmitted after request (see logic analyzer).

The master should read a constant value in this example. iam using the wire.h lib. pullup resistors on SDA, SCL 4.7kOhm.

**master.ino: esp8266** (working, sends requests)

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#define DEFAULT_SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x0A
void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus as master
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("\n Hello");
  delay(2000);
}
void loop()
{
  //Wire.beginTransmission(DEFAULT_SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  //Wire.write(0);
  //Wire.endTransmission();
  //delay(10);
  Wire.requestFrom(DEFAULT_SLAVE_ADDRESS, 1);
  Serial.println(Wire.read());
  delay(1000);
}
```

**slave.ino: atmega328p**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
volatile uint8_t nr;
void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(0x0A);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  //Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}
void loop()
{
}
//void receiveEvent(int howMany)
//{
//  while(0 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
//  {
//  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
//  }
//}
void requestEvent()
{
  nr = 99; 
  Wire.write(nr);  
}
```

Serial output from master: (got no val)

```
-1
-1
...
```

Logic analizer output:
[image: nack]

Wiring on atmega:
VALUE-PIN

- VCC 7
- GND 8
- SCL 28
- SDA 27

[image]

anyone got an idea whats missing?

**Edit: removed `receiveEvent()`, added CPU speed** and it worked

Comment: You seem to have a problem only with the read operation at the moment. I would remove the `onReceive` part to troubleshoot the problem and test if the example code works (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/MasterReader).

Comment: esp8266 is usually 3.3V while atmega328p is 5V - do your hardware setup take it in account? And have the voltage on SDA,SCL the right values for HIGH and LOW on BOTH master and slave?

Comment: Can you make your 328P's `loop()` do something, like blink an led so that you know the 328P is operational and at the correct frequency?

Comment: @SimSon thanks for your reply. when i removed the receiveEvent it worked. i figured out the the problem is the `Wire.available()` function on the atmega.

Comment: @gilhad the ATmega can be operated at 3.3V, I guess that's the case here. The ATmega also NACKs the read header, which means the address has been transmitted successfully. That doesn't make it look like a hardware issue.